# Current class topic

Tags: html, css

The current class on nav is not working. Can you please help me figure out why? I tried to use only the class, or the class with link, or any combination, but it's not working.

```
\\\

Here's the HTML part related to nav:
 <nav class="secondary_header">
      <ul> 
<li><a class="current" href="about.html"> ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="experience.html">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
<li><a href="knowledge.html">KNOWLEDGE</a></li>
<li><a href="goals.html">GOALS</a></li>
<li><a href="humor.html">HUMOR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    \\\

This is the CSS part:

    \\\
    .secondary_header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    clear: left;
}


    .secondary_header ul {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    
}
   .secondary_header ul li a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
    .secondary_header ul li:hover a {
    color: #f54242;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .secondary_header ul li current.a  {
    color: #f54242;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    \\\
```

Basically, I would like the color of the current state-the page you're on- to be the same as the hover state. Any suggestion is greatly and sincerely appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Error is here - `.secondary_header ul li current.a ` try `.secondary_header ul li a.current`

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you. It worked.